# How to bulk delete files from AWS S3 with PHP using the sdk?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-9

I have a Laravel 9.x project with PHP 8.x.
My project has a database/table for media files and the actual media is stored on AWS S3.
I basically am using just one bucket and two folders inside the bucket /photos and /videos.

My logic needs to query my table for all the media that has expired and then it will delete the media files from S3.

If I use the Storage class and delete one file at a time (like example below) it works fine. Which leads me to think my credentials must be OK.

```
Storage::disk('s3')->delete($filename);
```

However it takes way too long. For example when I ran the job last night it had to delete 148,000 files and it took 7.5 hours to run. Because I expect my volume will double every year for the next 3 - 5 years it will eventually have to run 24 hours a day and possibly not be able to keep up. Since the Laravel 9.x Storage class does not appear to support bulk deletes I am trying to write my own PHP and use the AWS SDK myself to delete multiple files from my bucket which is NOT versioned. The code I wrote below accepts an array of filenames as they would be inside the bucket and it breaks it into blocks of up to 999 (because the docs say 1,000 is the maximum).

```
    public static function awsBulkDelete($files)
{
    Log::info('============ awsBulkDelete ================');
    Log::info(json_encode($files, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    Log::info('===========================================');
    $region = config('aws.s3.region');
    $bucket = config('aws.s3.bucket');
    $s3 = new S3Client(['region' => $region, 'version' => 'latest']);

    $objects = [] ;
    $count = 0;
    $remaining = count($files);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $count++;
        $remaining--;
        $objects[] = ['Key' => $file];
        if (($count == 999) || ($remaining == 0)) {
            $count = 0 ;
            $results = $s3->deleteObjects([
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                'Delete' => ['Objects' => $objects,]
            ]);
            Log::info(json_encode($results->toArray(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
            Log::info('===========================================');
            $objects = [];
        }
    }
}
```

The code seems to be working except I am getting **Access Denied** for every file.
Below is a small example of the logs for listing the $files array:

```
[2023-01-04 11:37:56] production.INFO: ============ awsBulkDelete ================  
[2023-01-04 11:37:56] production.INFO: [
"photos/37944311-ae803150d2.jpg",
"photos/37944311-ae803150d2-thumb.jpg",
"photos/37944321-4de38fa1d5.jpg",
"photos/37944321-4de38fa1d5-thumb.jpg",
"videos/37944366-967bb1a35a.mp4",
"photos/37944366-967bb1a35a.jpg",
"photos/37944366-967bb1a35a-thumb.jpg",
```

And below is an example of what I am getting back for every request:

```
[2023-01-04 11:37:56] production.INFO: ===========================================  
[2023-01-04 11:37:56] production.INFO: {
"RequestCharged": "",
"Errors": [
    {
        "Key": "photos/26956180-00df1a5087-thumb.jpg",
        "Code": "AccessDenied",
        "Message": "Access Denied"
    },
    {
        "Key": "photos/37992171-09773b703f-thumb.jpg",
        "Code": "AccessDenied",
        "Message": "Access Denied"
    },
    {
        "Key": "photos/37992186-6c9c589710-thumb.jpg",
        "Code": "AccessDenied",
        "Message": "Access Denied"
    },
```

I can't figure out if this is a coding issue or if it is a permissions issue on my AWS account?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The IAM user that is being used has AmazonS3FullAccess permission but I noticed when I expand on that and go into the S3 portion it list like 100 permissions including DeleteObject

Comment: Please share the IAM policy(s) attached to your role and and the S3 bucket resource policy if one exists?

Comment: In the IAM for my user it has the Permission called AmazonS3FullAccess. For the bucket policy there is nothing listed in the memo below that heading. It does allow Public Read but not List and not Delete.